# NuxtJS Vuex Module namespacing and mutations enum

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I have a NuxtJS website with a Vuex store. I have a root state and a module located at `store/shop/cart/state.ts` with a `store/shop/cart/mutations.ts` file looking like this.

```
import { MutationTree } from 'vuex';
import { CartState } from './state';
import { Cart } from '~/types/Cart';

export enum CartMutations {
  SET_CART = 'SET_CART',
}

const mutations: MutationTree<CartState> = {
  [CartMutations.SET_CART](
    state: CartState,
    payload: { cart: Cart }
  ) {
    state.cart = payload.cart;
  },
};

export default mutations;
```

Inside my `middlewares`, I would like to commit the mutation like so.

```
store.commit(CartMutations.SET_CART, cart);
```

However, due to namespacing, the action is named `shop/cart/SET_CART`. So I would have to do this which is not the best since I cannot use my enum.

```
store.commit('shop/cart/SET_CART', cart);
```

Did someone run into this as well ? I'm wondering about a clean solution to workaround this while keeping the namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

this is where `mapMutations()` comes handy.

check out this [namespace binding explanation on official Vue doc](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing).

so what I would do in this case is

```js
// inside constant declaration file
export const SHOP_CART_STORE = 'shop/cart';

// inside component
import {SET_CART} from 'CartStore';

{
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(SHOP_CART_STORE, {setCart: SET_CART}),
    doTheJob(cart) {
      this.setCart(cart);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't use `mapMutations` since my usage is only for a single mutation and not inside my `components` but the `middleware` folder

Comment: What I'll end up doing IMO is defining this `export const CART_MODULE = 'shop/cart'` inside `store/shop/cart/state.ts`. And use it to prefix the `store.commit` like `store.commit(`${CART_MODULE}${DistributorConfigMutations.SET_CART}`, cart)`